# rspec and capybara "should find" shorthand

Tags: rspec, capybara

Is there a shorthand for `find` like there is for `have_selector`?

For example I can write:

```
it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Welcome')  }
```

Is there a similar shorthand for the following?

```
it "should have blank customer input" do
  find_field('CustomerName').value.should be_blank 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no shorthand as shorthands are RSpec Matchers.

You can't do it with `have_field` since it doesn't support attributes.

There is `have_css` matcher:

```
it { should have_css("#CustomerName[value='']") }
```

but it won't check value if it changed after page loaded.

Other [RSpec Matchers](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/RSpecMatchers) don't have ability to assert attributes too.